# Sort in Linux for column, keeping other values intact

Tags: sort

```
NODE_154_length  847 2997
NODE_154_length 3283    4509
NODE_154_length 4672    5715
NODE_154_length 6977    7768
NODE_29_length  3790    4317
NODE_29_length  4356    4712
NODE_29_length  4356    4712
NODE_29_length  158 319
NODE_29_length  1   97
NODE_29_length  1   96
```

I want the output like:

```
NODE_154_length  847 2997
NODE_154_length 3283    4509
NODE_154_length 4672    5715
NODE_154_length 6977    7768
NODE_29_length  1   97
NODE_29_length  1   96
NODE_29_length  158 319
NODE_29_length  4356    4712
NODE_29_length  4356    4712
NODE_29_length  3790    4317
```

**OR**

```
NODE_29_length   1   97
NODE_29_length  1   96
NODE_29_length  158 319
NODE_154_length 847 2997
NODE_154_length 3283    4509
NODE_29_length  3790    4317
NODE_29_length  4356    4712
NODE_29_length  4356    4712
NODE_154_length 4672    5715
NODE_154_length 6977    7768
```

`sort -k2,2 file` This sorts all column 2 and gives:

```
NODE_100_length_46867_cov_66.420166  1   50
NODE_104_length_141_cov_120.127663  1   210
NODE_104_length_141_cov_120.127663  1   210
NODE_104_length_141_cov_120.127663  1   225
```

This disturbs the complete coordinates for each node.

If I try `sort -k2 file` This again gives me weird output, not in sorted manner.

I am not able to understand how to use -k option in Linux.
I am using bash, Linux 13.10

Comment: `sort -k1,1 -k2,2n` or `sort -s -k2,2n`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas
Thank you for your reply. That works perfectly.
Can you please explain me, how that flags are working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is `-k<start>[<flags>][,<end>[<flags>]]` (if `,<end>` is omitted, that's the end of the line).

That defines the part of the line to sort on as one sort key.

`<start>` and `<end>` refer to field numbers. `2` for `<start>` means the beginning of the 2nd field, while `2` for `<end>` means the end of the 2nd field.

By default, fields are delimited by the transition between a non-blank and a blank. For instance, in:

```
NODE_154_length  847 2997
```

The fields are:

```
[NODE_154_length][  847][ 2997]
```

Doing `sort -k2`, sorts on the part of the line that starts at the beginning of the 2nd field and ends at the end of the line. So above, on `[  847 2997]`. `sort` is doing lexical comparisons be default.

`sort -k2,2` would consider only `[   847]` for comparison.

If you want to do numerical comparison on a particular key, you have to add the `n` `<flag>` to the sort key. That way,   `847` would be converted to a number. That's why `-k2,2n` and `-k2n` would work the same because both the `[  847]` and `[  847 2997]` *strings* convert to *number* `847`.

So, to get your first result, you want to sort on the first field lexicographically, and then (where the first fields sort equally) on the second field numerically. That's written:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n
```

In the second case, you want to sort on the second field numerically and when they sort the same, preserve the original order.

That's where you need the `-s` option for *stable* sort:

```
sort -s -k2,2n
```

(by default, where the keys sort the same, `sort` resorts to doing a lexical comparison of the whole line; `-s` disables that).